# How to create a DAG in Airflow, which will display the usage of a Docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, airflow

I'm currently using Airflow (Version : 1.10.10),

and I am interested in creating a DAG, which will run hourly,

that will bring the usage information of a Docker container ( disk usage),

(The information available through the docker CLI command ( df -h) ).

i understand that:
"If xcom_push is True, the last line written to stdout will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes"

but my goal is to get a specific value from the bash command,
not the last line written.

for example ,
i would like to get this line ( see screeeshot)

"tmpfs           6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup"

into my Xcom value, so i could edit and extact a specific value from it,

How can i push the Xcom value to a PythonOperator, so i can edit it?

i add my sample DAG script below,

[image: airflow log]

```html
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = { 
    'retry': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5) 
}

with DAG(dag_id='bash_dag', schedule_interval="@once", start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
# Task 1
    bash_task = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task', bash_command="df -h", xcom_push=True)
bash_task
```

Is it applicable?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: You can either run a CLI command using the `BashOperator` e.g`docker stats --no-stream --format '{{ json .}}' <container-id>` or otherwise use the docker python client library to obtain stats information

Comment: thank you very much @OluwafemiSule for the quick replay,
i edited my post, if you can, please have a look, thanks!

Comment: How about piping the output of df to tail command and pushing that to xcom. Your command then shall be: `df -h | tail -n 1`

Comment: thank you @OluwafemiSule,
this command do get the relevant line, and put it in the Xcom.
i still not sure how can i extract this line from the Xcom, and pass it on to a Python operator ( i want to do it, because i want to put the line into a python data frame, so i can split it to different parameters, 
my final goal from this DAG, is to print the following message: 
"the disk size is Size, used disk space is Used, available disk space is Avail"
for example, 
"the disk size is 6.2G, used disk space is 0, available disk space is 6.G".
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retreive the value pushed to XCom store through the `output` attribute of the operator.

In the snippet below, `bash.output` is an [XComArg](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/xcom_arg/index.html#airflow.models.xcom_arg.XComArg) and will be pulled and passed as the first argument of the callable function when executing the task instance.

```
from airflow.models.xcom_arg import XComArg
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import DAG

with DAG(dag_id='bash_dag') as dag:

    bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id='bash_task', bash_command="df -h", xcom_push=True)

    def format_fun(stat_terminal_output):
        pass

    format_task = PythonOperator(
                python_callable=format_fun,
                task_id="format_task",
                op_args=[bash_task.output],
            )

    bash_task >> format_task
```

Answer (score 0):

Yhis should do the job:

```html
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = { 
    'retry': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5) 
}

with DAG(dag_id='bash_dag', schedule_interval="@once", start_date=datetime(2020, 1, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
# Task 1
    bash_task = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task', bash_command="docker stats --no-stream --format '{{ json .}}' <container-id>", xcom_push=True)
bash_task
```

Comment: hi @Sashko Micov,
please notice that i edited my question,
i'm looking for a way to extract only a specific value via the bash command,
this syntax doesn't work, i got a 'Bash command failed' error, 
while the bash command 'df -h' works, not sure why.